# Calibrating Firefox Printing with CSS

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I understand that it is impossible to standardize printing with CSS between all browsers. However, I would like to attempt to ameliorate how Firefox is currently representing an HTML document on printing, by using a `.css` file and the `media='print'` query.

Currently I have a simple document which has a `#myImages` `<div>` to which `display:block` is applied, while the rest of the HTML document has `display:none` applied. 
This successfully isolates the `myImages` div on the page as the sole element.

My issue is that, when printing in Firefox (in all browsers, but I would like to make the fix for Firefox solely), is that there is a large left margin being applied to the printed page. I have in my CSS `#myImages{ margin: 0 !important}`. When I add the line `position:absolute; left:-20px` the printed material then bleeds off the left of the page. Is this a possible task to achieve?

Comment: Tried to remove the `left:-20px`?

Comment: `position: absolute; left: -20px;` is behaving exactly how it's designed. There is no CSS control over print margins in the browser. That's up to the user. If you need precision print layout control, you should generate a PDF on the server.

Comment: @aaronburrows but can the user theoretically change those settings in the browser?